# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The attribute prefix [fn] does not correspond to any imported tag library

Tags: java, servlets, web, jstl, tomcat8

I am trying to deploy and run the [Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) application using IntelliJIDEA 14.1.4
on Tomcat 8.0.14(`Tomcat Server -> Local`). The project was created using `maven-archetype-webapp` and later imported
to the IDE by specifying path to `pom.xml`.

Everything works fine as documented in the `servlets` tag info, but when I remove the following line:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
```

and add it in my `include.jsp`, I encounter an:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp (line: 18, column: 42) The attribute prefix [fn] does not correspond to any imported tag library
```

### Project structure:

[image]

### include.jsp

```
<%-- 'header' file that will be included in every JSP page ensuring the same definitions are included in all our JSPs. --%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
```

### index.jsp:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<c:redirect url="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp"/>
```

### hello.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Application Home</title>
  <style>.error {
    color: red;
  }
  .success {
    color: green;
  }</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="hello" method="post">
  <h1>Hello</h1>

  <p>
    <label for="name">What's your name?</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.name)}">
    <span class="error">${messages.name}</span>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="age">What's your age?</label>
    <input id="age" name="age" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.age)}">
    <span class="error">${messages.age}</span>
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit">
    <span class="success">${messages.success}</span>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Question:

Is it a bad idea to add the line only once(`include.jsp`) so that I can use it where required rather than adding it in every JSP or is the error cause because of something else which I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly, as it may seem, I missed the include statement in `hello.jsp` which was causing the exception. Posting the answer because I want to keep this information here for future reference.

Missing statement inside `hello.jsp`

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
```

### hello.jsp:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
....
</body>
</html>
```